# Question in set unions and differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X,Y,B$ are sets

Prove:

$X\cup B=Y\cup B$ **if and only if** $X\setminus B=Y\setminus B$

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Have you been able to prove one of the directions ("if" or "only if")?

Comment: These results are very easy to prove if you help yourself drawing a Venn diagram. Venn diagrams are so easy to be understood, that even childs understand them.

Answer (score 2):

We have $(A\cup B)\setminus B=A\setminus B$ and $(A\setminus B)\cup B = A\cup B$

And if $A=B$ then $A\cup C=B\cup C$.

Putting the two together gives the result.

Answer (score 2):

We have $X \cup B = Y \cup B$ iff $X=Y$ and iff $X \setminus B = Y \setminus B$.

Note that the behavior of $\cup$ and $\setminus$ is like the arithmetic sum and difference.